# How do I use the "-cpu" option in Qemu?

Tags: qemu

Using QEMU 0.14.1 under Ubuntu 11.10 with kernel 3.0.0-17-generic, if I run `qemu -cpu ?` I get:

```
$ qemu -cpu ?
x86           [n270]
x86         [athlon]
x86       [pentium3]
x86       [pentium2]
x86        [pentium]
x86            [486]
x86        [coreduo]
x86          [kvm32]
x86         [qemu32]
x86          [kvm64]
x86       [core2duo]
x86         [phenom]
x86         [qemu64]
x86           [host]
```

...but when I run:

```
$ qemu -snapshot -m 256M -cpu x86 -hda live-usb.img 
Unable to find x86 CPU definition
```

I've tried `x86`, `486`, `x86-486` as well, with no success. So how do I actually use the CPU option?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
qemu -M pc-0.14 -cpu core2duo -m 256 [-option argumentyouwant] live-usb.img
```

x86 is a CPU architecture is not an exact CPU, in CPU option you must use a CPU not architecture.

Comment: Perhaps you could point him out why it wasn't working as well?

Comment: But `-cpu 486` didn't work either.

Comment: Okay, it worked today... I must've made a typo when I tried it. Oh well, if it works it works!

Answer (score 0):

You can use [DOSBOX](http://www.dosbox.com/) if you want a 486 computer with DOS, Or Virtualbox if you want a fast virtualisation.

Comment: Alas neither — I need to boot an existing live USB image using a 586 (or similar) architecture. Virtualbox might still be able to help with the latter I suppose, but I won't be able to check until Monday.

Comment: USB was generally absent in age of 586.... (There was USB 0.9 in FX mainboard, but that is no more considered USB)
-cpu 486 works fine for me, i add -boot a/b/c/d to make it boot from "removable" device. Otherwise it uses -boot cad i.e looks for nonexistent CD and floppy first.

Comment: the embedded system I'm using is a 586 (or maybe a 686) architecture, and has several USB ports available (including BIOS support for USB booting).